# Why is this JSON decode failing?

Tags: json, swift

I have done JSON decoding before, but for some reason I can't figure this out. In the playground, it simply crashes with no explanation so I decided to put it into a single view project to trace the problem.

The initializer isn't being called at all. Tried decoding with the super class and got the same thing. Would love another pair of eyes on this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let json = """
{"key": 5, "accountKey": "checking", "amount": 100000, "type": "deposit", "date": "2019-03-05T15:29:32Z", "locationKey", "Payroll", isReconciled: false}
"""

        let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        let transaction = try? decoder.decode(BasicTransaction.self, from: jsonData)
        print(transaction?.locationKey)
    }
}
```

Here are the supporting definitions:

```
enum TransactionType: CaseIterable {
    case purchase
    case deposit
    case ccPayment
}

extension TransactionType: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = String

    init(rawValue: Self.RawValue) {
        switch rawValue {
        case "deposit": self = .deposit
        case "payment": self = .ccPayment
        default: self = .purchase
        }
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .purchase: return "purchase"
        case .deposit: return "deposit"
        case .ccPayment: return "payment"
        }
    }
}


class MoneyTransaction: Decodable {
    var key = UUID().uuidString
    var type = TransactionType.purchase
    var accountKey = ""
    var ccAccountKey: String? = nil
    var recurringTransactionKey: String? = nil
    var isRecurring: Bool { !(recurringTransactionKey ?? "").isEmpty }
    var locationKey: String? = nil
    var addressKey: String? = nil
    var categoryKey: String? = nil
    var note: String? = nil
    var amount: Double = 0

    private enum MoneyTransactionKey: String, CodingKey {
        case key, type, accountKey, ccAccountKey, recurringTransactionKey, locationKey, addressKey, categoryKey, note, amount, isNew
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("initializing MoneyTransaction")
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MoneyTransactionKey.self)

        key = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .key)
        accountKey = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .accountKey)
        let rawAmount = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .amount)
        amount = Double(rawAmount / 100)
        type = try TransactionType(rawValue: container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type))
        recurringTransactionKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .recurringTransactionKey)
        locationKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .locationKey)
        categoryKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .categoryKey)
        note = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .note)
        ccAccountKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .ccAccountKey)
        addressKey = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .addressKey)
    }
}


class BasicTransaction: MoneyTransaction {
    var date = Date()
    var checkNumber: Int? = nil
    var isReconciled = false

    private enum BasicTransactionKey: String, CodingKey {
        case date, checkNumber, isReconciled
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("initializing BasicTransaction")
        try super.init(from: decoder)
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: BasicTransactionKey.self)

        date = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .date)
        checkNumber = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .checkNumber)
        isReconciled = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isReconciled)
    }
}
```

Comment: catch this `let transaction = try decoder`

Comment: @Sh_Khan That wasn't what was keeping the initializer from being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json is incorrect it's like

```
{
    "key": 5,
    "accountKey": "checking",
    "amount": 100000,
    "type": "deposit",
    "date": "2019-03-05T15:29:32Z",
    "locationKey", << key with no value
    "Payroll", << key with no value
    isReconciled: false  << key with no ""
}
```

It would be like

```
{
    "key": 5,
    "accountKey": "checking",
    "amount": 100000,
    "type": "deposit",
    "date": "2019-03-05T15:29:32Z",
    "locationKey":"",
    "Payroll":"",
    "isReconciled": false
}
```

then `BasicTransaction`

```
class BasicTransaction: Codable {
    let key: Int
    let accountKey: String
    let amount: Int
    let type: String
    let date: Date
    let locationKey, payroll: String
    let isReconciled: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case key, accountKey, amount, type, date, locationKey
        case payroll = "Payroll"
        case isReconciled
    }

    init(key: Int, accountKey: String, amount: Int, type: String, date: Date, locationKey: String, payroll: String, isReconciled: Bool) {
        self.key = key
        self.accountKey = accountKey
        self.amount = amount
        self.type = type
        self.date = date
        self.locationKey = locationKey
        self.payroll = payroll
        self.isReconciled = isReconciled
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to validate my JSON